How to implement mention/hashtag highlight in input/textarea in react?
Just like whatsapp have this feature, where when we mention user with "@" in input it gets highlighted and rest of the text remain same!

how can to implement this in react ?
(*custom implementation needed, not any npm)
I tried using separate div and dangerouslySetInnerHTML, it worked just visually
but i want it to be editable just like an input field.
code :


import React, { useState } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [inputVal, setInputVal] = useState("");

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setInputVal(e.target.value);
  };

  const formatText = (text) => {
    const formattedText = text.replace(
      /(@\w+)(\s|$)/g,
      `<span style="color: red;">$1</span>$2`
    );
    return { __html: formattedText };
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <textarea
        type="text"
        placeholder="Add message..."
        value={inputVal}
        onChange={handleChange}
        style={{ width: "100%", height: "100px" }}
      />
      <div
        style={{ whiteSpace: "pre-wrap", color: "black" }} 
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={formatText(inputVal)}
      ></div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;



output :

this is just a sample, i thought i'll hide the textarea and keep the div editable but it didn't worked that way.


<div
   contentEditable = "true"
  aria - placeholder = "Add message..."
  role = "textbox"
  // data-lexical-editor="true"
  onInput = {
  (e) => setInputVal(e.target.innerText)
          }
  style = {{
    whiteSpace: "pre-wrap",
    color: "black",
    border: "1px solid red",
    width: "100%",
    userSelect: "text",
    maxHeight: "200px",
    outline: "none",
    // minHeight: "40px",
    // wordBreak: "break-word",
  }}
  dangerouslySetInnerHTML = {formatText(inputVal)} >
</div>




Why would you use dangerouslySetInnerHTML? Can you upload your implementation as code so we can see what you have tried to do?

I've included code
